# How to use ObjC block typedefs in Swift2 (esp. when containing BOOL parameters)

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks, typedef, swift2

After moving on to Xcode7 (beta5) and Swift 2, I'm getting errors in my Swift code regarding `Bool` (or `BOOL` / `ObjCBool`) values that are passed from (or into) closures with an Objective-C `typedef`.

```
typedef void (^completion_success_block_t) (BOOL success);
```

When I use this type in my Swift class, I'm getting compiler errors.

```
func doSomething(completionBlock : completion_success_block_t) {
    doSomethingElse { success in
        if success == true { } // (1) error 1
        let foo : Bool = true
        completionBlock(foo) // (2) error 2
        completionBlock(true) // (3) works just fine! 
    }
}
// error 1: "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ObjCBool' and 'Bool'"
// error 2: "Cannot invoke 'completionBlock' with an argument list of type '(Bool)'"

func doSomethingElse(completionBlock : completion_success_block_t) {
    completionBlock(true)
}
```

Why does line (3) compile just fine, but not line (2)?
It seems like the compiler does convert between `ObjCBool`s and `Bool`s in some cases but not always.

It feels like using my ObjC `typedef` is like telling the compiler: 'I really want this to be an `ObjCBool`, not a `Bool`, so please don't do any conversions for me'. But that's not what I want. My code was working perfectly fine in Xcode 6.

Now I only see two options:

1) convert all values manually before passing / using them: `let swiftSuccess = Bool(success)` and `let objCFoo = ObjCBool(foo)`

2) stop using the ObjC `typedefs` for blocks containing `BOOL` parameters

Is there a better way? Perhaps changing the block signature in the `typedef` to work with both Swift and ObjC? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool! **Apple fixed this** in Xcode Version 7.0 (7A218). Now passing a Swift `Bool` to a closure that was an ObjC typedef with a BOOL parameter works just fine. Comparing the `BOOL` parameter with `true` or `false` in Swift works as well.

Only downside for me: now all my workaround lines of code (e.g. `completionBlock(ObjCBool(true))`) cause compiler errors (sometimes even of the slightly obscure `Segmentation fault: 11` type). Have to revert it all back. Sigh... (thank god there's git)